# Why does 'delete document' in lucene 2.4 not work?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to delete a document in lucene 2.4 with java. My code is

```
  Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory("c:/index");
  IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
  System.out.println("num="+indexReader.maxDoc());
  indexReader.deleteDocuments(new Term("name","1"));
  System.out.println("num="+indexReader.maxDoc());

 output 
         num=1
         num=1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion it is best to use Indexwriter to delete the documents, since Indexreader  **buffers the deletions** and does not write changes to the index until [close()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#close()) is called on.; unless  you use the same reference for search.

The [Lucene wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-9475b5b51f7ca022e03dbd94cb82b4a6c02e3675) states

> Generally it's best to use IndexWriter
>   for deletions, unless
>
> you must delete by document number
>
> you need your searches to
>   immediately reflect the deletions or
>
> you must know how many documents
>   were deleted for a given
>   deleteDocuments invocation

I can see you want the maxdoc value for the document in memory so its a better approach to use Indexwriter

so the answer for your question is

you should close the Indexreader object or use Indexwriter for deletions

Comment: faced same issue. I use indexWriter and even call commit, close after deletion. Changes are not reflected in memory and disc. Update works fine

Answer (score 3):

`maxDoc()` won't change until you optimize the index using an `IndexWriter`. At the very least, you need to `commit()` or your delete may never even make it to disk.

However, `numDocs()` should return the number of non-deleted documents even before a commit or optimize.

It's probably better practice (and certainly less confusing) to use an `IndexWriter` to add and delete documents and to open your `IndexReader`s read-only; 3.0 will open them read-only by default.